# Microsoft Botframework Emulator Error

Tags: botframework

I followed the instructions that were given in the online tutorial (Building a bot from 0 to 60), but the emulator doesn't work. It keeps on telling me "401 unauthorized". I looked online and some of you suggested that https should be used. However, when I did so the emulator displayed a message saying it cannot connect to a remote server. Some of you also suggested changing Appid to MicrosoftAppid and doing the same thing with the password, but again that didn't work. Some of you even suggested leaving both the Appid and password blank in both the emulator and Web.config and that didn't work as well.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? (I also made sure that everything (like the port and my Appid and password) was written correctly, so there shouldn't be any syntax or user errors).

Thanks

Comment: Can the vendor maybe help?

Comment: Which version of the emulator are you using? I'm not sure the new one (Microsoft Bot Framework Channel Emulator 3.0) is supposed to work with bots build with the old version (Bot Framework V1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v3.0.0, please note that there is currently an issue with authentication if you use node.js. The suggested workaround is to deactivate authentication by not handing over any appId and appPassword in your connector options in your bot and do not use any auth data in your emulator.

Also note as @Thegaram said that you use a matching emulator to the botbuilder version you use. If you have the v0/v1 of botbuilder, you should use the Bot Framework Emulator (v1), if v3+, then the Bot Framework Channel Emulator (v3+). They will have trouble connecting to mismatching versions.